# how to create multiple retrofit base url in dagger hilt and inject them

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-hilt

I am new in dagger hilt I am using @Named annotation to make unique but I have no idea how to use. I want to create multiple retrofit base Url object and inject here is my code

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@LiveUrl
fun provideRetrofitInstance(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    gsonConverterFactory: GsonConverterFactory): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(LIVE_SERVER)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
        .build()
}
enter code here

@Singleton
@Provides
@BlogUrl
fun provideRetrofit2Instance(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    gsonConverterFactory: GsonConverterFactory): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(LIVE_BLOGSERVER)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
        .build()
}
```

class RemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(
private val liveApiInterface: NewApiInterface
)
{

}

Comment: i do not see any response from u. how did it go?

Comment: Add the annotation `@Name("Retrofit1)` and `@Name("Retrofit1)` for each Retrofit `@Singleton` instances. And when `@Inject`/use time, add the corresponding `@Name("...")` for your Retrofit.Builder singletones

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multiple Retrofit APIs with different urls, you could also consider using Assisted Injection:

```kotlin
@AssistedFactory
interface RetrofitFactory {
    fun create(baseUrl: String): RetrofitBuilder
}

class RetrofitBuilder @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted val baseUrl: String,
    val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
) {
    inline fun <reified T> build(): T {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(...)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
            .create()
    }
}
```

This can then be used like:

```kotlin
@Provides
fun provideLiveApi(retrofitFactory: RetrofitFactory): LiveApi =
    retrofitFactory.create(API_BASE_URL).build()
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done in a few ways. i will explain you two ways you choose what is best for you.

lets say you need retrofit object that connects to `@LiveUrl` endpoint and you need in the `RemoteDataSource` class as per your question.

```kotlin
class RemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(
    @LiveUrl liveUrlRetrofit: Retrofit,
    @BlogUrl blogUrlRetrofit: Retrofit,
){
    private val liveUrlApi = liveUrlRetrofit.create(LiveApi::class.java)
    private val blogUrlApi = blogUrlRetrofit.create(BlogApi::class.java)

}
```

above is the simplest way.

if you have a very big project. i suggest you to create a module that provides multiple API's as below

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class ApiModule {
    @Provides
    internal fun liveUrlApi(@LiveUrl liveUrlRetrofit: Retrofit) = retrofit.create(LiveApi::class.java)

    // so on and on and on
}
```

now inject this to your `RemoteDataSource` in a lazy way. I will leave this as your homework